# How do I override rails naming conventions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, pluralize

I have a model named "clothing" which I want to be the singlular (one piece of clothing).  By default, rails says the plural is clothings.  Right or wrong, I think it will be more readable if the plural is "clothes".

How do I override the plural naming convention?  Can I do it right in the model so I don't have to do it over and over?  How will this change how routes are handled (I am using restful architecture)?

Comment: how about changing your model to garment and garments?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6178900/1505348

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I'm no RoR expert, but did find a [possible approach](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html). From the referenced site you can add inflection rule inside the `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file:

```
# Add new inflection rules using the following format 
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'clothing', 'clothes'
end
```

Comment: Actually, your custom inflections should reside in config/initializers/inflections.rb

Comment: For those who are lazy like me: `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|` if it doesn't find Inflector on it's own

Comment: I like your approach. If I had many "custom" inflections, I would save them in a yaml and load the file in that same archive.

Comment: If passed an optional locale, rules for other languages can be specified. If not specified, defaults to **:en** which will provide rules for english language.  
  `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en)`

Answer (score 28):

For rails 2.3.2 and maybe 2+, you need to do it a little different:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1\2en'
    inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'

    inflect.irregular 'octopus', 'octopi'

    inflect.uncountable "equipment"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your `environment.rb` file if you are trying to stop database pluralization

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

Answer (score -1):

With Ruby 2.2.2 windows or linux for me best solve was :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false

class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
end


personas = Persona.all
personas.each do | personita |
  print "#{personita.idpersona}   #{personita.nombre}\n"
end

p Persona.count
```