# ruby on rails pluralization help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

My app is gonna be in spanish.
Say I want to scaffold generate actividad. the plural would be actividades so I want the table and the controller  to be named that .... how can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the following code in config/environment.rb:

```
Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'actividad', 'actividades'
end
```

Test the code in the console (script/console):

```
'actividad'.pluralize
'actividades'.singularize
```

**More details can be found here:** 
[http://codeidol.com/other/rubyckbk/Web-Development-Ruby-on-Rails/Understanding-Pluralization-Rules/](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can add your own pluralizations to Rails by adding inflections.  Rails should have a file called inflections.rb under /config/initializers.  You can add it there if it isn't.  My file as an example (comments come from Rails):

```
# Add new inflection rules using the following format
# (all these examples are active by default):
# Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
#   inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
#   inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
#   inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
#   inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
# end

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural(/rion$/ ,'ria') # criterion => criteria
  inflect.singular(/ria$/, 'rion') # criteria => criterion
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to write your code in English, and use [the i18n api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to present the content in Spanish and other languages if/when necessary.

Comment: This is a very "open-sourceic" POV. In real world applications, you often find yourself coding classes out of the customers business model. Translating them into english is sometimes not just a bad idea, it could also break the agreement!