# NameError: uninitialized constant -- activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I have two classes, Number and Freebie:

```
class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :freebies

end

class Freebie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :number

  attr_accessible :name, :data

  has_attached_file :data, :path => "freebies/:id_partition/:filename"

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

All of my other classes with a has_many and belongs_to relationship work fine, but when I call something like:

```
n = Number.last
n.freebies.create
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Number::Freeby
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in `transaction'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:431:in `create_record'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:119:in `create'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `create'
    from (irb):20
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/Robby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've had some other problems with the Freebie class because it ends with ie and Rails tries to make the singular version "Freeby" instead of Freebie. Still, I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails automatically tries to infer the plural version of a word from its singular form and vice-versa. You might want to look into overriding the default inflection rules.

Try something similar to the answer in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640408/ruby-on-rails-pluralization-help).

Comment: Yep, that did it! I put the following in my initializers/inflections.rb file:

`ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'freebie', 'freebies'
end`

And now I can call n.freebies.create fine.

Thanks for pointing me there!

Answer (score 0):

```
"n.freebie.build"
```

does the same thing you are trying to do. 
Let me know if it works.