# Issue with scaffold in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying out a few things in Rails and I got a particular issue with the scaffolding process. It might be something I'm not familiar with, let me show you what I did:

First:

```
rails g controller painel painel
```

to create a simple front page
Second:

```
rails g scaffold Noticia title:string category:string tags:string text:text
```

Then I repeated the same line but changing the name like so:

```
rails g scaffold Artigo title:string category:string tags:string text:text
```

and I did the same with `Ideia` and `Analise`.

Done that I looked at the files structure and the controllers for Noticia and Ideia were `noticia_controller.rb` and `ideia_controller.rb` but the other two were `artigos_controller.rb` and `analises_controller.rb` , two were plural and two singular. Naturaly the first two didn't work out on the page as they should and I tried to repeat the same process again and again just to get the same result. I'd appreciate any ideas on the matter, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby on rails pluralization help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640408/ruby-on-rails-pluralization-help)

Comment: not a duplicate @BradWerth, different issue, but thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is... 
`'noticia'.singularize` => `"noticium"` and
`'noticia'.pluralize` => `"noticia"`

Comment: Additionally, this is the same issue that Rayn Bigg addresses in his answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the pluralization rules in Rails being better suited for English than for other languages.

I would strongly recommend avoiding the scaffold generator and just generating your controllers and models using these two commands:

```
rails g controller artigos
rails g model artigo category:string
```

And then building out from there.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it might be the case! I tried a few tests and it appears to be something related to 'ia' sufixes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, long term, to make a new inflector, to handle this same issue elsewhere throughout the application?