# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord: pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, pluralize

I'm new to Rails, so forgive my ignorance of ActiveRecord.  One of my models is named "campus".  I ran the migration and it pluralized everything except "campus".

I thought that was lame so I added the code to the environment config to leave everything singular.

I deleted the tables, manually edited the migration files to use singular forms, and re-ran the migrations.  Now my associations to "campus" no longer work.  I ran it through the console and noticed that I'm getting an uninitialized constant "Campu".  So something still thinks "campus" is plural?  Should I assume that config change will cause me nothing but trouble going forward?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use custom inflections. See this related question: [How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  No need to fight the convention.