# rails can`t pluralize word 'affiche'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

I have a model called `affiche` and model `user`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :affiches

class Affiche < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

And there i get an error, trying to fetch from db:

```
uninitialized constant User::Affich
```

if it didn`t erased the `e` letter it would be nice, i think.

Is there any way to tell how to pluralize words rails doesn`t know about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: How do you explicitly define plural names and singular names in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517989/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-explicitly-define-plural-names-and-singular-names-in-ra)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom inflection rules in the file `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.  There are examples in that file's comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the class name of the children as an option to `has_many`. Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :affiches, class_name: 'Affiche'
end
```

See http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many for further examples.