# I created a scaffold in rails called Cove. In the controller, the instance variable is automatically named @cofe. Why is that happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Here are the steps I did. In command line:

> rails new lcdemo
>   rails generate scaffold Cove title:string

(created an entry in seeds.rb)

> rake db:migrate
>   rake db:seed

In the controller and view files, instance variables are named cofe instead of cove.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The reason

```
"cove".pluralize
=> "coves"
"coves".singularize
=> "cofe"
```

### The solution

You can edit your config/initializers/inflections.rb file to create a custom inflection to teach Rails that the singular of "coves" is "cove".

```
inflect.irregular 'cove', 'coves'
```

Answer (score 2):

That'll be the Inflector working its magic. It looks like it's pluralizing "Cove" to "coves" in order to make the table name, and then singularizing "coves" (by analogy with "wolves", "knives" etc) to "cofe".

I don't know if it'll work, but you could try adding the following to `config/initializers/inflections.rb` before you run the scaffold generator?

```
inflect.plural "cove", "coves"
inflect.singular "coves", "cove"
```