# override default pluralize for model-name in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, pluralize

my locale is :de and I like to get this:

```
Sheet.model_name.human.pluralize # => Belegs
```

to add me a trailing "e" instead of "s"

```
Sheet.model_name.human.pluralize # => Belege
```

just for the Sheet-class.
Can I add it somehow in my config/locales/models/de.yml ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1185035/1505348

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all, you need to stop using `.pluralize`. It uses the Inflector (which is mainly used for Rails internals, e.g. guessing table names for model Sheet -> sheets).

```
Sheet.model_name.human # => "Beleg"
"Beleg".pluralize # => "Belegs"
```

What you should do is to use the `:count` option.

```
Sheet.model_name.human(:count => 2) # => "Belege"
```

This requires that you have modified your `de.yml` as such:

```
de:

  ...

  activerecord:

    ...

    models:
      sheet:
        one: Beleg
        other: Belege
```

Comment: looks good, I tried but seems to not work for model-class-names.

Comment: I added an explanation why you can't use pluralize. The inflector isn't meant to solve i18n problems.

Comment: Model name in the locale file should be singular, not plural ("sheet", not "sheets").

Comment: @Marcel Jackwerth : Just curious. In the YAML file, you use "one" and "other". Is there an equivalent to "other" in the `human` function (eg `Sheet.model_name.human(:count => lots)`? It just seems odd to put 2 in there if there can be hundreds of entries..

Comment: @Shawn Actually you can use `100000` or anything you want. Using `:count => "foo"` will lookup the `other` translation as well. The current implementation only checks `:zero if count == 0` and `count == 1 ? :one : :other`. Here is the [full code](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/v0.6.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L132).

Comment: this works and looks quite good (if a bit hacky), but is it the recommended standard way to do it? any references?

Answer (score 15):

You can override pluralizations this way:

In `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

do:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'Beleg', 'Belege'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like explicit count number (like 2) you could use `:many` e.g.

```
Sheet.model_name.human(count => :many)
```

or without hash rocket (for Ruby >= 1.9):

```
Sheet.model_name.human(count: :many)
```

Comment: Hash notation is not Rails-related. The new syntax came with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, `:many` isn't special. It will always select `:other` unless you pass in `1` e.g.

`Sheet.model_name.human(count: :awesome)`