# Rails controllers names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I'm new in Ruby on Rails world. I want to use singular controller name instead of plural.

Here is the url that I want to achieve.

http://foobar.com/admin/login

Here is what I try

```
rails g controller admin::login
```

When I try to access

```
http://foobar.com/admin/login
```

I get

```
uninitialized constant Admin::LoginsController
```

How to create singular controller instead of plural?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you go against Rails convention, the first thing you have to ask yourself is why are you doing it that way? If you are creating a login function, you should have an administrators/users controller and a sessions controller. You can still create the url /admin/login/ by using nested resources and custom routes, but have the logic in the sessions controller.

But if you really need to change that for some reason, you can do it using this type of technique: [override default pluralize for model-name in rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178900/overide-default-pluralize-for-model-name-in-rails3).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [rails namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) first. For example:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts, :comments
  match 'login' => 'controller#action'
end
```

It will produce routes with `admin` prefix.
So if you want singular controller you should dive deeper into inflectors. Check following links:

- [Pluralizations and Singularizations (Inflections) in Rails 3](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2011/06/pluralizations-and-singularizations-inflections-in-rails-3/)
- [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html)

For example, add following lines to your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "login"
end
```

In general you should user `user` or `session` controller for `login` action, of course. Look at, for example, [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) for more information and usage.