# spanish locale in rails - model names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I looked around and it seems that to set pluralization rules for model names you put the following in your locale file

```
# es.yml
es:
    activerecord:
        models:
          business:
            one: Lugar
            other: Lugares
```

However, when the model name is translated in plural, I still get `Lugars` instead of `Lugares`

Not sure what's wrong

Comment: Looks like the line `activerecord:` and below are indented too far out, is that just a copy-paste problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with `Business.model_name.human(:count => 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are mixing up two forms of pluralization of strings in Rails. The first is meant for *internal* purposes: for naming classes, variables, methods, table names, etc. This is `pluralize`, and to make it properly handle exceptions etc. you can define inflections in config/initializers/inflections.rb.

But this type of pluralization is *not* appropriate for translations. For that, you should use `Business.model_name.human(:count => 2)` (as @doesterr suggested), which will reference the locale file for the locale you are in, which is what you want.

For details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178900/overide-default-pluralize-for-model-name-in-rails3#6179686).