# Rails generate wrong pluralize form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.9, when I do the following in a rails console:

1.9.3p125 :003 > "foot".pluralize
 => "foots"    # shouldn't it be "feet"?

1.9.3p125 :004 > "tooth".pluralize
 => "tooths"   # shouldn't it be "teeth"?

1.9.3p125 :009 > "goose".pluralize
 => "gooses"   # shouldn't it be "geese"?

is that a bug in rails pluralize or I did something wrong?

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate, but this question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6178900/247763

Answer (score 10):

You can configure the rails inflector. There should be an initializer file in your application to do so: `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

You can then add a call to "teach" rails the new rule:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'tooth', 'teeth'
end
```

After you restart the server/console the new pluralization should be in place.