# How to get accurate pluralization with Rails pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

I need very accurate pluralization for my application

I am currently using the Rails built in pluralization method.

I found a problem with the word 'foot'.

When I do:

```
"foot".pluralize(2)
=> "foots"
```

The correct pluralization should be feet.

How can I get more accurate results?
I have looked for other gems and they all seem to make the same error.

Comment: this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096407/rails-generate-wrong-pluralize-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define below code inside your config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'foot', 'feet'
end
```

- there are some of plural are not define yet, so you need to define it inside inflections.

Comment: Thanks that words great.