# Rails 4: pluralizing model_name.human using count: 123 doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, pluralize

From Rail 3, I'm used to do this:

```
User.model_name.human count: 2 # "Users"
```

This doesn't seem to work in Rails 4?

```
[1] base »  User.model_name.human count: 2
=> "User"
```

While pluralizing a simple string seems to work:

```
[2] base »  "User".pluralize
=> "Users"
```

Any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6179686/724036 looks like you should modify yml language file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This requires that you have modified your language *.yml as such:

```
activerecord:
  ...

  models:
    sheet:
      one: User
      other: Users
```

[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178900/overide-default-pluralize-for-model-name-in-rails3/6179686#6179686)

Comment: It's a duplicate, but I check it as answer. Thank you!