# Rails 2.3.9 pluralize model names issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

I'm developing a simple select. The thing is my code needs to be in spanish, so
instead of using Role I have to use Rol (the plurar remains the same: Roles).

So, my model name is: Rol and my Controller name: Roles and in my DB: Roles

```
<% roles = Rol.all %>
<%=  collection_select(:usuario, :rol_id, roles, :id, :nombre, {:prompt => true}) %>
```

However, when I run that code I get:

> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Table
>   'turaser2.rols' doesn't exist: SELECT
>   * FROM `rols`

(for obvious reasons)... So, my question is: how can I tell rails to look into the "roles" table instead the "rols" table?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I override rails naming conventions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to do something like:

```
set_table_name "roles"
```

in your model.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to add a new entry to the inflector. If you only set the table name with `set_table_name`, the pluralization will still fail anywhere else you may want to use it.

Go to `config/initializers/inflections.rb` and add:

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.irregular 'rol', 'roles'
 end
```