# Rails routes oddity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my routes.rb

```
scope :path_names => {:new => "creaza", :edit => "modifica", :sign_up => "inregistreaza", :sign_in => "autentificare", :sign_out => "iesire", :show => "vezi"} do
......
resources :nota, :only => [:new, :create]
......
end
```

And here is the output of rake routes:

```
....
nota POST   /nota(.:format)                                          nota#create
new_notum GET    /nota/creaza(.:format)                                   nota#new
....
```

What? notum? Where does 'notum' come from?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

"notum" is Rails's attempt to depluralize "nota". [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions) contains some information on how to override these plurals, and [here's an article](http://viget.com/extend/rails-internationalization-and-tu) about adapting the inflector for languages besides English. See also [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-singular-form) in the routing guide.