# NameError: uninitialized constant when calling form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

-My routes.rb

-resources :manufacturers do
 - resources :vehicle_data
-end

-In controller

- def create
- @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
- @vehicle_data = @manufacturer.vehicle_data.create(params[:vehicle_data])
- @vehicle_data.save
  -end

-In Views

-<%= form_for([@manufacturer, @manufacturer.vehicle_data.build]) do |f| %>

-When trying to create new record

-NameError in Vehicle_data#index

-Showing C:/Users.../app/views/vehicle_data/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

-uninitialized constant Manufacturer::**VehicleDatum**
-Extracted source (around line #12):

-9: 
-10: 
-11: 
-12: <%= form_for([@manufacturer, @manufacturer.vehicle_data.build]) do |f| %>
-13:
-14:

How do I make this form work??? Why the model name is changed from VehicleData to VehicleDatum

Answer (score 3):

Rails expects models to be the singular form of the resource you defined, and the singular of data is datum, so it expects your class to be a `VehicleDatum`. If this isn't the pluralization that you want to use, see [How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

Comment: Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'VehicleDatum', 'vehicles'
end                                                             +Getting error NameError: uninitialized constant Inflector

Comment: try putting it in config/initializers/inflectors.rb and use `ActiveSupport::Inflector` as in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html