# Do rails MVC naming convention work with words which plural form is "-ies" (e.g. replies)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was thinking of creating a model called `Reply`. I was wondering if Rails knows that its plural form is `replies` and not `replys`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Comment: Why not just try it? It would surly be faster to run `rails g model reply` and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe it internally relies on the [pluralize method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize), so you can check in a rails console what is the result of a particular pluralisation :

```
"reply".pluralize
=> "replies"
```

So the answer to your question is yes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Rails may or may not know the plural form of any word, but if it doesn't you can teach it by adding it to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.