# Non-standard pluralization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, pluralize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

When you generate new models in Rails, it pluralizes the table name automatically. However, this doesn't always work out well – particularly with words that have non-standard pluralizations.

I created a model called `lens`. Since rails thought the word was already pluralized, it didn't pluralize the table name in the migration file. No problem – I just edited the file and changed `lens` to `lenses` before running the migration.

Unfortunately, I get this error when trying to instantiate the Lens class:

```
Could not find table 'lens'
```

I'm assuming this is because Rails thinks the word is already pluralized, so it doesn't try to pluralize it when trying to find the table in the database.

So what do I do? Should I break from convention and just let Rails call the table `lens` instead of `lenses`, or is there a way to configure this properly?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file where you can do something like.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'lens', 'lenses'
end
```

Comment: Perfect! I popped those lines in and it worked perfectly. Thanks!