# Rails creating wrong table name for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I'm creating a model named `Stadium` with `rails g model Stadium` but rails is converting table name to `stadia`.

I've manually changed table name to `stadium` in the migration, and added `set_table_name "stadium"` in my model class. But all my routes are looking for `stadia_path`.

I've tried `rails g model Stadium --force-plural` with no success.

I think I should use an inflection for this, but I don't know how to create this inflection.  Stadium is singular, I still need the plural stadiums for this model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dictionary says that both "stadiums" and "stadia" are correct (given that the word is Latin, "stadia" as plural for neuter words ending in -um seems legitimate).

Just add this to config/initializers/inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'stadium', 'stadiums'
end
```

You can set up all kinds of irregular plurals here.

Destroy your old generation by doing

```
rails d model Stadium
```

and generate it again doing

```
rails g model Stadium
```

You will see how it magically creates files like this:

```
db/migrate/20130330130335_create_stadiums.rb
```

Then run the migration and you're set!

Answer (score 2):

For inflections you have to something like this in the `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'stadium', 'stadiums'
end
```

hope it helps!