# Uninitialized constant in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :exes
end
```

Exe:

```
class Exe < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

What I am getting in my view on `http://localhost:3000/posts/index` is:

```
NameError in Posts#index
uninitialized constant Post::Ex
```

It says just `Ex` for some reason.

The code of line ruby is complaining on is `<% post.exes.each do |exe| %>` which looks right to me.

So I don't really know why this is happening. If have also checked the following as i thought this might be the reason but no:

```
2.0.0-p247 :004 > ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('Exe')
 => "Exes" 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > ActiveSupport::Inflector.singularize('Exe')
 => "Exe"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that ActiveSupport::Inflector is assuming that a word that ends in 'xes' in the plural form must end in 'x' in the singular form. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions) for help on customizing pluralizations.

**Update:** Somehow I missed the last part of your question.  You said you tried:

```
> ActiveSupport::Inflector.singularize('Exe')
```

but did you try:

```
> ActiveSupport::Inflector.singularize('Exes')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For some reason I missed out on checking `singularize('Exes')`. That 'xes' must end in 'x' just didnt come to my mind because I am german and not quite familiar with english :) - Works fine now!

Comment: That's the standard form for pluralization in English. E.g. "box" => "boxes", "tax" => "taxes".  A Rails lesson and an English lesson for the price of one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Define the inflector for this particular string in your project's inflections initializer:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'Exe', 'Exes'
end
```

Remember that you'll need to restart your server before changes will take effect.