# Rails 3 vs Rails 2 pluralization issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 2 in my ruby on rails application.

In rails console when i try

```
"police".pluralize
```

then i get something like this:

```
"poluce"
```

I spent some time on searching this issue but haven't got proper answer.
Any clue about this ?

I tried it in Rails 3 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more or less a duplicate of this question:

[How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

The key being that you can add any custom inflections that you want.  To see a difference between Rails 2 and Rails 3 is not surprising. In fact, it is encouraging.