# Ruby on Rails - Define plural name of Model or Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, plural

I have this model

```
class Oferta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entidade
  has_many :candidatos, :through => :interesses
  has_many :interesses, foreign_key: "oferta_id", dependent: :destroy
```

basically I have this model and model `Interesse` and its plural its `interesses` but I think Rails is actually taking off the  `es` at the end and leaving me with Interess. And now it gives me this error:

```
uninitialized constant Oferta::Interess
```

How can I define that the singular to `interesses` is `interesse`? and not `interess`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'interesse', 'interesses'
end
```

Comment: yeah. i saw the link above. But yeah that's pretty much what I did. thanks for the answer. I'll accept it as soon as I can

Comment: Based on the above link, your custom inflections should reside in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

Comment: Yeah putting it in inflections.rb is a best practice. Thanks @Rahul