# how to use inflections on a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have created an engine with

```
rails plugin new myengine --mountable
```

when searching for 'inflections' in the project folder, i find the 
**/test/dummy/config/initializers/inflections.rb** file

in this file i put

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'singular_model', 'plural_model'
end
```

when i try to use the model generator (from project root)

```
bin/rails generate model singular_model
```

then i get the a migration with **singular_models** as the table name and migration name

when i run the same command from myengine/test/dummy

```
bin/rails generate model singular_model
```

i get the spected result: **plural_model** as table name and migration name

so, how can i load the inflector into the rails generator?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Answer (score 3):

At your engine, you must think on your `test/dummy/` folder as the root of the app that is using this engine. This folder only exists for testing purpose, is not a setting for the engine.

Let say your engine is at folder `myengine` and your app is at folder `myapp`.

1) If you want a custom inflection, which is defined at engine level and it be used at the engine and at the app level. Then it must be defined in:

```
# myengine/config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'singular_model', 'plural_model'
end
```

Yes, you must create the folder `initializers` and the file `inflections.rb` in it. And this inflection will be valid for each app that use the engine.

2) If you want your custom inflections works only for your app, but not for others apps that use the same engine. You must use the same code at yours `myapp/config/initializers/inflections.rb`, this file does exists by default in a Rails app.

In this last case the scope of the custom inflections is only the current app, just like at the `test/dummy` folder.

Depending on what behavior you need, is where you must put the code of your custom inflections.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually create a file named `inflections.rb` in project _root/config/initializers/ and write your rules in that file for e.g.,

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new inflection rules using the following format. Inflections
# are locale specific, and you may define rules for as many different
# locales as you wish. All of these examples are active by default:
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
#   inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
#   inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
#   inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
#   inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
    inflect.irregular 'cloth', 'clothes'
end

# These inflection rules are supported but not enabled by default:
# ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
#   inflect.acronym 'RESTful'
# end
```

And it gets applicable to the engine as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions

Comment: @DineshSaini Please read the question again.. I don't think you actually understood the question

Comment: Did this work? I've got the same issue and my engine is ignoring the additional inflections initializer.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.2, rails engines do not load the initializers when running generators, which is discussed in this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14472

### Workaround

1. Define inflections in `my_engine/config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

   ```
   # my_engine/config/initializers/inflections.rb

   ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
     inflect.irregular 'regatta', 'regattas'
   end
   ```
2. Require the inflections initializer in the `engine.rb`:

   ```
   # my_engine/lib/my_engine/engine.rb

   require_relative '../../config/initializers/inflections'

   module MyEngine
     class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
       # ...
     end
   end
   ```
3. Use the generator as expected: `bin/rails g model Regatta`