# NoMethodError for a method that exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well, i'm new to rails, but not new to the rails way and i've got an error that i dont know how to fix it.

I've created the controller and than the view.

Controller:

```
class ReclamacoesController < ApplicationController

    def new
       @reclamacao = Reclamacao.new
    end
end
```

and than, the view under Views>controllerName>new.html.erb.

```
<%= form_for @reclamacao do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field  :titulo %>
<% end %>
```

The model Reclamacao exist.

I've created the resource routes for it too.

```
resources :reclamacoes
```

So, when i access /reclamacoes/new an exception is thrown.

```
NoMethodError in Reclamacoes#new 
undefined method `reclamacaos_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000001fc0660>:0x00000001fba850>

Extracted source (around line #1):
<%= form_for @reclamacao do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field  :titulo %>
<% end %>

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/aqueleprojetoprivate/medicos
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/reclamacoes/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_reclamacoes_new_html_erb___3194888715597102324_16164860'
```

the routes:

```
     reclamacoes GET    /reclamacoes(.:format)          reclamacoes#index
                 POST   /reclamacoes(.:format)          reclamacoes#create
   new_reclamaco GET    /reclamacoes/new(.:format)      reclamacoes#new
  edit_reclamaco GET    /reclamacoes/:id/edit(.:format) reclamacoes#edit
       reclamaco GET    /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#show
                 PATCH  /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#update
                 PUT    /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#update
                 DELETE /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#destroy
```

What is wrong?

Comment: there is a typo if you closely look..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is trying to automatically guess plurals. The problem is that your resource is `reclamacao` which Rails is turning into `reclamacaos` plural. But you have named it as `reclamacoes`

I suggest either changing names or instruct Rails to use better plurals. Here's a relevant article: [How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

Comment: What would you suggest me? Declare irregulars or try to rename it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your language but you should change your code according to your needs, not otherwise ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the output from `rake routes`. You will notice a spelling error

```
reclamacoes    GET    /reclamacoes(.:format)          reclamacoes#index
               POST   /reclamacoes(.:format)          reclamacoes#create
new_reclamaco  GET    /reclamacoes/new(.:format)      reclamacoes#new
edit_reclamaco GET    /reclamacoes/:id/edit(.:format) reclamacoes#edit
reclamaco      GET    /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#show
               PATCH  /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#update
               PUT    /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#update
               DELETE /reclamacoes/:id(.:format)      reclamacoes#destroy
```

Based on the above output, the correct path name is `reclamacoes path`.

Rails emphasizes `Convention over Configuration`, and you have different spellings in your models, views and controllers.

Comment: well, i thought the reclamaco was a typo from them, and there was no space in the columns to put the right name. Should i rename or declare plurals?

Comment: Add this line `resources :reclamacaoes`. This is why your routes were generated wrong