# How does rails handle model names with unusual pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a model called Match.  Will the table for Match be matches or matchs i.e pluralizing with 'es' instead of the normal 's'?  If I have another table, Player,  belonging to Match, should the reference be `match_id`?  If rails understands how to plularize Match, what other unusual pluralizations does it accept e.g. a model called Misery which would have a normal pluralized form of miseries?

Comment: It will be `matches`. When in doubt, just open `rails console` and type `"match".pluralize`. Rails hands the *vast* majority of English pluralizations correctly. It's completely open source, and the source code is available on your local machine, unobfuscated. You can step through it using a debugger if you want to figure out how it handles various English pluralization rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on meagar's comment, most english pluralizations are done correctly in rails. If in doubt, you can just open a rails console and type 'model_name".pluralize e.g.

```
'match'.pluralize
```

which returns 'matches'.  If this doesn't work, then you can roll your own according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185051/1299362).